# How do i create a one to one match on 2 variables, when those two variables have many to many, but the entire row is one to one, using pyspark or sql

Tags: python, databricks, matching

I have 2 data sets.

A: Data set 1 
[image]

B: Data Set 2 
[image]

I want to end up with Results 
[image]

If I use a join or a merge I end up with

```
      date  amount description  ID
0  1/1/2023      10         abc   1
1  1/1/2023      10         abc   2
2  1/1/2023      10         zyx   1
3  1/1/2023      10         zyx   2
4  1/3/2023      15         fff   3
5  5/1/2023     500         gtz   4
6  5/1/2023     500         gtz   5
7  5/1/2023     500    alkdatha   4
8  5/1/2023     500    alkdatha   5
9  6/1/2023      62         adt   6
```

I really don't care which description and ID go with each other if the date and amount match.  I just want them to only be in the results once.  so my total should be 1097

I have tried

```
# Sample data for dataset 1
data_1 = {'date': ['1/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '1/3/2023', '5/1/2023', '5/1/2023', '6/1/2023'],
      'amount': [10, 10, 15, 500, 500, 32],
      'description': ['abc', 'zyx', 'fff', 'gtz', 'alkdatha', 'adt']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)

# Sample data for dataset 2
data_2 = {'date': ['1/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '1/3/2023', '5/1/2023', '5/1/2023', '6/1/2023'],
      'amount': [10, 10, 15, 500, 500, 62],
      'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

# Convert the "amount" column to integers
df_1['amount'] = df_1['amount'].astype(int)
df_2['amount'] = df_2['amount'].astype(int)

# Merge datasets on common columns (date, amount)
merged_df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['date', 'amount'])

# Drop duplicate rows
merged_df = merged_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'amount', 'description', 'ID'])

# Display the result
print(merged_df).
```

I also tried this with join instead of merge.

Comment: If you order your rows within each date group (1 to N) and then use that new order column in your join, I believe that would do what you are wanting, right? Like `df_1['rn'] = df_1.sort_values(['date']).groupby('date').cumcount()`

Comment: Thanks.  This is so straight forward.  I banged my head for a while.  This will work.